# Specifying nodes to use for slurm array jobs

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to run an array job on specific nodes using `--nodelist` but I'm not sure it's possible.

E.g. I want to set:

```
#SBATCH --array=0-1
#SBATCH --nodelist=compute-[0,2]
```

and have the first subjob end up on compute-0 and the 2nd on compute-2. However the nodelist gets duplicated for each subjob in the array. Setting `ntasks` or `ntasks-per-node` doesn't help as they apply to each subjob too.

Any solutions?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. You can't have different SBATCH parameters for different array jobs, that's not what they're for.

What exaclty are you trying to achieve? Should the jobs run at the same time on two different nodes?

Comment: Well I kinda get that but I was hoping there was a workaround. Yes the jobs should run at the same time, on different nodes. Basically I want to launch N single-node MPI jobs and have each job's output in a separate file. But N will likely be in the 1000s and submitting that many jobs at once generally makes the scheduler unhappy so was hoping I could do it with array jobs.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for them to run at the same time? As in, do they have to run concurrently, or do you just want to have as many jobs running as possible? Why exactly do you need specific nodes?

Comment: I'm trying to run a test script on each node to burn them in. So they don't really have to run concurrently - there's no inter-node comms - but they do use on-node MPI. I've worked around it with an exclude list which is probably the only way of doing it really, I just wondered if I'd missed something.